# Export XML column rows from SQL table into individual files

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table called `REFERENCES` that contains a few hundred thousand rows of XML that I would like to extract as individual XML files.

It is roughly formatted as such:

```
+--------------+------------------+
| REFERENCE_ID | REFERENCE_XML    |
+--------------+------------------+
| 1            | <xml>...</xml>   |
| 2            | <xml>...</xml>   |
| 3            | <xml>...</xml>   |
| 4            | <xml>...</xml>   |
| ...          | <xml>...</xml>   |
| 70000        | <xml>...</xml>   |
+--------------+------------------+
```

I would like to loop through every row and bulk export each `REFERENCE_XML` column and name it as the `REFERENCE_ID`.

My output folder set would look as such:

```
C:\References\1.xml
C:\References\2.xml
C:\References\3.xml
C:\References\4.xml
C:\References\...
C:\References\70000.xml
```

I was able to find a rough query that performs the operation for a single static row, but I am having a difficult time figuring out the best way to create a `WHILE` loop or `CURSOR`. How do I make the file name and `WHERE` clause dynamic to loop through every row in the `REFERENCES` table and export all the XMLs as individual files?

```
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @fileName = 'C:\References\1.xml' -- I need the integer value to be dynamic per row.
SET @sqlStr = SELECT REFERENCE_XML FROM REFERENCE_DB.dbo.REFERENCES WHERE REFERENCE_ID = 1'  -- I need the REFERENCE_ID to be dynamic per row.
SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to create a running number directly on starting a `CURSOR`. This seems easier than to call a full `SELECT` on any iteration.

**Edit**: I was to fast. You want to use your `ReferenceID` as number. Just go the same way without `ROW_NUMBER()` and read the ReferenceID into `@Nr` on each iteration.

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeXml xml);
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (100,'<root><test a="1"/></root>')
,(200,'<root><test a="2"/></root>')
,(300,'<root><test a="3"/></root>');

DECLARE @Nr BIGINT,@ID INT,@SomeXml XML;
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS Nr,ID,SomeXml FROM @YourTable ;
OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Nr,@ID,@SomeXml;   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

    SET @fileName = 'C:\YourPath\' + CAST(@Nr AS VARCHAR(100)) + '.xml' ;
    SET @sqlStr = 'SELECT ''' + CAST(@SomeXml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '''';
    SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T';

    PRINT @sqlCmd;
    --EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Nr,@ID,@SomeXml;    
END   

CLOSE cur;   
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

This is the print-out:

```
bcp "SELECT '<root><test a="1"/></root>'" queryout C:\DVP\1.xml -w -T
bcp "SELECT '<root><test a="2"/></root>'" queryout C:\DVP\2.xml -w -T
bcp "SELECT '<root><test a="3"/></root>'" queryout C:\DVP\3.xml -w -T
```

Comment: With a few modifications (in particular to the @sqlStr line), I was able to successfully get this working. I didn't find it necessary to cast the XML as an NVARCHAR. bcp was able to process the XML without any issues. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately xp_cmdshell does not accept (n)varchar(MAX), maximum is nvarchar(4000)/varchar(8000). The the xml is longer, it will be truncated and the result will be invalid. Must use global temp table (##) because bcp use a different connection, so "normal" temp table does not work. I tried to use bcp with table variable as a workaround but it is also unavailable for bcp.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT REFERENCE_ID FROM REFERENCE_DB.dbo.REFERENCES
OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
INTO @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @fileName = 'C:\References\' + @id + '.xml'
    SET @sqlStr = SELECT REFERENCE_XML FROM REFERENCE_DB.dbo.REFERENCES WHERE REFERENCE_ID = ' + @id
    SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T'

    EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
END
CLOSE myCursor;
DEALLOCATE myCursor;
```

Comment: This `...WHERE REFERENCE_ID = ' + @id` will not work without a cast, 'cause `@id` is declared as `INT`